# Ctrl Key KeyUp event with Click in table heading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I want to generate keyup event with `<th>`. If i click in `<th>` click event is populating there but my requirement is generate event when i release <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key pressed with click in `<th>` area I am using the following code

```
<html>
<head>
<script
 src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
 integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="2">
<th>rollno</th>
<th>name</th>
<tr>
<td>4567</td>
<td>john</td>
 </tr>
</table>
 </body>
 <script>
 $('th').click(function(){
 alert("yes its working");
 });
 </script>
 <script>
 $('th').on('keyup', function(e) {
 if (e.keyCode ==17)
 {
 alert("OOps! ctr+click release not working");
 }  
 });
 </script>

 </html>
```

Comment: so basically you want an event, when its clicked over `th` and mouse is still `down`, and `ctrl` key is `up`? or you want an event `ctrl+click`?

Comment: Look at my requirement i want pop up  User click with CTRL key Pressed and after that as user releases the CTRL key whether <TH>  is still clicked or not doesnt matter pop up should be there

Comment: What is this i want the action on CTRL key release not with CTRL+CLICK

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ma0vt2zj/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like that ?

```
$('th').click(function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey){
        alert("yes its working");
    }
});
```

EDIT :

```
$( 'th' ).click( function ( e ) {

    if ( e.ctrlKey ) {

        $( window ).on( 'keyup' , function () {

            alert( "yes its working" );

            $( window ).off( 'keyup' );

        } );

    }
    else {
        alert( 'nop' );
    }

} );
```

Comment: Dear this will show alert message when i click with CTRL key but i want when i release CTRL key After CTRL+Click

Comment: I have edited the code.

Comment: yes now working thansk

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('keyup',function(event){
 if(event.which=="17"){
    cntrlIsPressed = true;
}
else{cntrllsPressed=false;}
});
 $('th').on('click ', function(e) {
 if (cntrllsPressed==true)
 {
 alert("OOps! ctr+click release not working");
}
});
$(document).on('keydown',function(event){
    cntrlIsPressed =false;
});
```